# How can b-ok.cc website track my number of books downloaded even after using TOR browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

There is this website https://b-ok.cc/s/ I was using to download some book I needed. This website has a daily limit of 5 book downlods per day and it does this by tracking the IP I was using. So I switched to Tor browser hoping that this time my IP will be hidden and will be able download more. To my surprise, the website could still recognise me only this time with a different IP.

My question is, how is this website able to recognise my connection even after using a Tor browser

Edit: To recreate this, go to  https://b-ok.cc/s/ and download 5 books. On your 6th download you will receive a warning that says "WARNING: There are more than 5 downloads from your IP  during last 24 hours."

Comment: I would like the answer to this question, too.

Comment: Why don't you use two or three different browsers or use the Tor browser, and change your exit node a few times. The only way they could know you after five downloads, and doing any of the above would be if you had signed in with some ID and password to do the downloading. Ouyside of that, they would have to be paying attention to the kinds of books that you are downloading, but even then they would be over-reacting, and especially so if you would have waited a few hours between downloads. You think?

Comment: Are you asking us to circumvent the terms & conditions of this website?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've got a TOR-NODE IP which already had downloaded 5 books these day. Just check if the 2 ips are the same. I bet these are not. The ip is just blocked too its not about you ;)